# Why isn't my Doctype showing up?

Tags: php, html, css, doctype

I have recently migrated a website to a new server. Everything went fine except when I noticed a couple of CSS bugs. I then realized that `<!DOCTYPE html>` was missing when I checked the source code of my newly migrated site. This is strange because the files are exactly the same as the old ones : same encoding.

The doctype is displayed on each page via PHP :

```
function displayHeader($title, $state, $css = '') {
  $langue = getLang();

  echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

     ...
```

The code is exactly the same on my old pages and my new ones, but looking at the source code in a navigator, the old ones begin with `<!DOCTYPE html>` while the new ones starts directly at `<!--[if lt IE 7]>`...

I cannot figure out why the doctype is shown in one version of my site and not the other. Any ideas ?

Comment: Worked fine for me on latest FF. Which browser are you using? - HTML source `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->...`

Comment: Tested with the latest FF, Chrome and IE 11... the old site works with all whereas the new one does not show a doctype in any of them.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes instead of single?

Comment: What happens if you remove the conditional comments?

Comment: That is just too bizarre.

Comment: Changed to double quotes and removed the conditional comments to no result.. I really don't get it